# User.register method of passport-local-mongoose but adding multiple properties?

Tags: node.js, passport-local

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose) the method is the next one:

```
User.register({username:'username', active: false}, 'password', function(err, user) {
   ...
});
```

But what if my User model has more properties such as address, firstName, lastName, etc?

How can I add the other properties?

Answer (score 1):

After dealing with many errors I found the answer.

1.-Create the new model coming from the form you created:

```
const newUser = new User({
    name: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    address: req.body.address,
    username: req.body.email
  })
```

You always need "username" otherwise it won't work.

2.- Call the method User.register

```
User.register(newUser, req.body.password , function(err,user){
  if(err){console.log(err); res.redirect("/register")}
  else{
    //A new user was saved
    console.log(user + "2");
    passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
      res.redirect("/")
    })
  }
})
```

As you can see the first param is no longer {username : ".."} instead the method is going to send all of the properties of the model to your mongoDB. And the second param is **ALWAYS** the password of the user, becuase the method is going to hash it and salt it.